# Is there any valid way to include a Point feature in geoJSON if the coordinates are unknown?

Tags: geojson

The Point I'd like to include is a marking on a historical map. Most of the items on the map have been located, so they make valid geoJSON Points. A few locations can not be identified, but I'd like to include them in the geoJSON file for completeness. As best I can tell, `coordinates: []` and `coordinates: null` are rejected by geoJSON readers. Is there another option?

Comment: Use an empty geometry instead of empty or null coordinates. Like this: `geometry: null`. According to section 3.2 of the standard, JSON readers "shall" accept this. "shall" is stronger wording than the "may" used for an empty coordinate array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoJSON readers do not need to reject a geometry with an empty coordinate array, but they may do so:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1

> A GeoJSON Geometry object of any type other than "GeometryCollection" has
> a member with the name "coordinates". The value of the "coordinates"
> member is an array.  The structure of the elements in this array is
> determined by the type of geometry.  GeoJSON processors MAY interpret
> Geometry objects with empty "coordinates" arrays as null objects.

What GeoJSON readers you have been using? If empty geometries fit to the data model of the reader you could file a feature request for the program or library that you are using.

I am not sure if I interpret right the output of ogrinfo, but it seems to me that it understands that the following GeoJSON contains an empty point as a geometry.

GeoJSON:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": null, "geometry": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[]} }
]

}
```

Output of ogrinfo:

```
ogrinfo point.json -al
INFO: Open of `point.json'
      using driver `GeoJSON' successful.

Layer name: point
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 1
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
OGRFeature(point):0
```

Comment: I uploaded my file to http://geojson.io/ and it was rejected. Perhaps I should try a more substantial platform, since it looks like an empty array isn't automatically invalid.  Thanks!